# Not sure how to get a number instead of a letter for the output without using indexOf()

Tags: java, string, substring, string-length

Prompt:

> Write a program that declares a string variable, assigns it "I'm still confused!  do I like programming   or I don't?", and then uses the `substring` method to extract and output the substrings shown below from that string.  You should also manually find the right index/position number for each '?'  ( don't use `indexOf()` ) and hardcode them in the `println` statements in your program so that it displays numbers instead of the "?" characters.

My code is as follows:

```
public class substring{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        String confused = new String("still confused! do I like programming  or I don't?");

        // first line 
        System.out.println("Substring starting from index? " + confused);

        //second line
        System.out.print("Substring starting from index? and ending at? : ");
        String c = confused.substring(6,14);
        System.out.println(c);

        //third line with length
        System.out.print("The length of the substring from index ? and ending at ? is: ");
        System.out.println(c.substring(c.length() - 1));
    }
}
```

I keep getting a "d" instead of an "8" and I cannot use `indexOf()` to get the "8". The output for the last line should look like:

```
The length of the substring from index ? and ending at ? is: 8
```

Comment: So you want to print `c.length()`?

Comment: You can use loop and check if char at index from loop is '?' if yes print position.